# Could not find the required 'adsf' gem, which is necessary for the view command

Tags: ruby, nanoc, asdf-vm, adsf

I was recently working on a project in nanoc and installed `bundler` so I could use `guard` to watch the project directory.

Now when I run `nanoc view` the webserver doesn't start up displaying the following error instead:

```
$ nanoc view
Could not find the required 'adsf' gem, which is necessary for the view command.
```

I read in a [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nanoc/_8cf6ydQogg/le55gFpCezQJ) that there has been some sort of a typo in which the gem packages `adsf` and `asdf` have been confused.  I tried installing both of them with `sudo gem install` but I when I run the command I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `gem "adsf"` to your `Gemfile`, and run `bundle` command. And, then run `nanoc view`. Should work.

Comment: In general, when working with Rails (instead of just Ruby or a different Ruby framework), you use your Gemfile to manage gems instead of installing them directly.